# How to turn off Contempt in engine analysis?

Tags: software, stockfish, python

I'm trying to analyze a game with the python-chess package, and for that I want to turn off the "Analysis Contempt" option in Stockfish. However, it seems it doesn't work, and I don't know why. Neither configuring the engine nor setting the option did the job - the evaluation flips every move in a simple opening line (Spanish) - it gives white the advantage on white move and the same for black. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I tried with both Stockfish 12 and Komodo 11 as the engine (where I set "White Contempt" to 0 instead of "Analysis Contempt".

```
def get_best_move_score(board: chess.Board) -> int:
    engine_path = os.environ.get('STOCKFISH')
    engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci(engine_path)
    engine.configure({'Analysis Contempt': 'Off', 'Contempt': "0"})
    analysis = engine.analyse(board, chess.engine.Limit(depth=20),
                              options={'Analysis Contempt': 'Off', 'Contempt': "0"})
    return analysis['score']


os.environ["STOCKFISH"] = "coach/charts/stockfish12"
file = open("coach/charts/game.pgn", encoding="utf-8-sig")

game = chess.pgn.read_game(file)
board = game.board()
previous_move = None
for move in game.mainline_moves():
    score = get_best_move_score(board)
    board.push(move)
    print(previous_move, score)
    previous_move = move
file.close()
```

Comment: https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/issues/2208 This site states that the contempt that is always on is dynamical contempt, which increases evaluations for continuations with more material on the board.